# How do I link the music samples to the iTunes store to purchase them?

Tags: iphone

I created my application with displaying songs list. I add "Buy" button to my application. When I will click "Buy" button, then it will ask purchase, and then the song will be download from iTunes.

So, first I will add songs to iTunes. Then only when I will click "Buy" button, after then the song will be download to IPhone from iTunes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Link to an iTunes song / album from iPhone app.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242424/link-to-an-itunes-song-album-from-iphone-app)

Comment: See also [How to link to the iTunes store from iPhone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893604/how-to-link-to-the-itunes-store-from-iphone-app)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link to an iTunes song / album from iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242424/link-to-an-itunes-song-album-from-iphone-app)

Answer (score 0):

You may have to do this statically. Apple has created a Link Maker that may help:

http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/